# tabindex stops in a particular element

Tags: angularjs, tabindex

I am using Angular JS in my application. I am using tabindex on certain clickable elements to support keyboard users for the application.

My understanding about tabindex is that suppose an element A gets tabindex = 1, element B gets tabindex = 3, element C with tabindex = 2, then the order of tabbing will be A -> C -> B. Then the loop continues.

I have provided the following code snippet. This part is actually a modal, which appears on top of another page:

```
<div data-ng-if="true">
    <a tabindex="1" data-ng-click="function1()">Change Password</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a tabindex="2" data-ng-click="function2()">Manage</a>
</div>
```

So when we start tabbing the expectation is that change password with tabindex 1 will be highlighted and then Manage with tabindex 2. Then the loop continues. However, the tab stops at Manage

Did anyone face a similar issue?

Comment: Tab is not focusing `Change Password`?

Comment: So when I start tabbing, the tabindex will highlight for "Change password", then for the next tab, it goes to "manage". When I again press tab, the highlight stays with "manage" only. Ideally, it should go back to "Change password". That is the issue I am facing.

Comment: Please provide plunker for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently got a task for looping focus on elements through tab and shift-tab. So, I create a custom directive. Working demo can be found [here](https://codepen.io/ajsun/pen/qKvGOz).

**Updated HTML**:

```
  <div data-ng-if="true">
    <a tabindex="1" id="idChangePassword" focus-next="idManage" focus-on-tab="0" data-ng-click="function1()">Change Password</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a tabindex="2" id="idManage" focus-next="idChangePassword" focus-on-tab="1" data-ng-click="function2()">Manage</a>
  </div>
```

**Directive code:**

```
angular.module("myApp.directives", []).directive("focusNext", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.bind("keydown", function(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        console.log(e);
        if (code === 9 && e.shiftKey === true && attrs.focusOnTab === "0") {
          e.preventDefault();
          document.getElementById(attrs.focusNext).focus();
        } else if (
          code === 9 &&
          e.shiftKey === false &&
          attrs.focusOnTab === "1"
        ) {
          console.log("tab");
          e.preventDefault();
          document.getElementById(attrs.focusNext).focus();
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Note that **TAB** press focuses next element and **SHIFT-TAB** press focuses previous element.

**How to use the directive?**

If you want to focus element Y from element X on **SHIFT-TAB** press, then add `focus-next="idofY" focus-on-tab="0"` in X element.

If you want to focus element X from element Y on **TAB** press, then add `focus-next="idOfX" focus-on-tab="1"` in Y element.

Make sure that the elements which needs to be focused supports **tabindex** by default and if not then **add tab-index="0"** to that element.

Answer (score 1):

- If **tabindex** is a negative value, you can't focus it by using
  `tab` press.
- If it is zero, that is the first focusable element in the document.
- If it is positive number, elements will be focused in ascending
  order
- **If elements contains same tabindex, order in html is matters. Focused
  in the order in which they are created in html**

for more info, read [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

Most importantly, **the browser url box is with tabindex 0**

Answer (score -1):

I think tabindex works in reverse order, i.e. if A = 1, B = 2 and C = 3, then the order is C>B>A.